# Can php get value from another page's url?

Tags: php, get, jquery-load

I want to use jQuery to make a page partly refresh. Page b is loaded in page a. And page b has a mysql search which gets values depending on a URL rule. So is it possible for PHP to get a value from another page's url? Thanks.

page a:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pageContent').load('B.php');
    });
</script>
<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

page b:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function pagination(page)
    {
        window.location = "a.php?more="+document.form.more.value;
    }
</script>
<form name="form" action="a.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="more" value="<? echo $_GET['more'];?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: You could echo your get variables inside your javascript as js variables so you can use them in your js call.

Comment: @Michael, how to post variables from js to php?

Comment: You can just use a echo.

Comment: On page A extract the value from URL using jQuery and assign it to variable. Pass the variable to any page you load (in this instance B.php) by passing the parameter in the URL (B.php?more=YOUR_MORE) or if you prefer using Ajax POST.

Comment: @LukeP, How to set `YOUR_MORE`? it depends on the search key word from `page B`,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pageContent').load('B.php?var1=test&var2=test');
    });
</script>
<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

page B

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function pagination(page)
    {

        window.location = "a.php?var1=<?php echo $_GET['var1'];?>&var2=<?php echo $_GET['var2'];?>&more="+document.form.more.value;
    }
</script>
<form name="form" action="a.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="more" value="<? echo $_GET['more'];?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, one question, what is `test`(var1=test&var2=test)? How Should I set it?

Comment: You can use them to pass parameters to your php file and render a page depending on there value: `var1=displayComments&var2=hideheader...`

Comment: @yuli var=test could be variable1 = 'value' so search='keyword' you can use that to pass the variables from page A to page B